# Deny Multiple Login Override in config

Tags: config, login, config-overrides

Is there a way to disable Deny Multiple Logins via a $config override?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [allow_multi_logins] => n in your config.php for this.  Make sure it's in the same format as the other config items.

You can find the full list in the wiki, via the Wayback Machine: [EE 2 Config Overrides](http://web.archive.org/web/20120621185434/http://expressionengine.com/wiki/EE_2_Config_Overrides).

Comment: Note, devot:ee has this covered for you! http://devot-ee.com/ee-config-vars

Comment: Devot-ee rocks.  Will link there in the future, thanks Derek!